# Haskell Socks Client request

Tags: http, haskell, networking, socks

I'm writing a client that listens the request via SOCKS5 from my browser. Then connect to the target server and perform http action via the client, then send the result back.

However I have no idea how to perform the HTTP(S) request.

I'm using the `Network.Simple.TCP`

```hs
serverb :: IO ()
serverb =
  serve (Host "127.0.0.1") "8000" $ \(connectionSocket, remoteAddr) -> do
    x <- recv connectionSocket 64
    print (B.unpack <$> x)
    send connectionSocket (B.pack [0x05, 0x00])
    t <- recv connectionSocket 1024
    print t
    case t of
      Nothing -> return ()
      Just t' -> do
        let (tAddr, tPort) = getADDR ((B.unpack t') !! 3) t'
        send connectionSocket (B.pack [0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])
        print tAddr
        h <- recv connectionSocket 1024
        print h
        -- don't know how to do the rest
    putStrLn $ "TCP connection established from " ++ show remoteAddr

getADDR :: Word8 -> ByteString -> (ByteString, ByteString)
getADDR t x = bimap B.pack B.pack $ go ([], f t s)
  where
    s =  B.unpack x
    f x = if t == 0x03 then drop 5 else drop 4
    go (p, [a, b]) = (p, [a, b])
    go (a, (b : bs)) = go (a ++ [b], bs)
```

The `getADDR` extracts `DST.ADDR` and `DST.PORT`.

I think I'm getting the full HTTP(S) request in `h` as `ByteString`, but I don't know how how to perform the request.

some of the contents in `h`

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive (I'm not showing all of request)
```

Can anyone give some hints on what I should do and what packages are needed?